# Проблема с выполнением bat-файла

Tags: python, bat

Задача: Нажав на ярлык bat-файла запустить программу на Python.
Код в bat:

```
cd "D:\YaDoperations"
python YaDoperations.py
pause
```

Проблема: Если ввожу в начале второй строчки python/python3 на выводе получаю лишь

```
Python
```

Не ввожу python/python3:

```
"YaDoperations.py" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Как быть?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: добавь python в переменную окружения, должно сработать

Comment: как это сделать? Вся загвоздка в том, что если я вручную прописываю эти команды в терминале - все работает, а после такой "автоматизации" нет

Comment: Панель управления->Система и безопасность->Система->Дополнительный параметры системы->Дополнительно->Переменные среды 
Там выбери ```Path``` и добавь путь к папке в которой лежит ```python.exe```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут есть 2 варианта решения:

1. Добавить путь к `python` в переменную среды `Path` (https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path)
2. Писать такие bat-ники:

```
python "D:\YaDoperations\YaDoperations.py"
pause
```

Comment: как-то так? Если верно - к сожалению не помогло
https://skr.sh/s6iAtHn5nas?a

Comment: @НикитаРазуваев а что у вас, собственно в `.py` файле, который вы запускаете ?

Comment: по сути простая программа, которая принимает команды из консоли иногда, никаких импортированных библиотек кроме time и sys нет. Я сначала подумал, что лучше сразу сделать standalone и не парится с этим, но стало интересно, как реализовать запуск этим методом